# How to resolve gitbook-cli Maximum call stack size exceeded error?

Tags: node.js, npm, gitbook

I install ubuntu18 server and node, npm, gitbook-cli on it, version info:

`node -v:`
`v8.10.0`

`npm -v:`
`3.5.2`

`gitbook --version:`
`CLI version: 2.3.2`
`GitBook version: 3.2.3`

My gitbook repository: https://github.com/linrongbin16/Way-to-Algorithm

When I build pdf with `gitbook pdf ./ ../algo.pdf --debug`

It output error message:

`RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Answer (score 0):

My case, I'm trying this & IT's working for me...

```
npm rebuild
```

And than try your command...